# How to set parent-child forms in Metropolis?

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio

In VCL, I used dynamic loaded `.bpl` packages and open Forms inside these packages as child forms.

How to do that in a FireMonkey Metropolis application?

I have a project with a Main Form and a package. I can dynamically load the needed package, but in FireMonkey there is no child Form type.

Comment: Packages work the same way in FMX as they do in VCL. Please show the actual code you are having trouble with.

Comment: Hi. For now I do not have any problem with a code...
I can load packages but I have a problem with a concept of application...
Actually question is: how to set parent-child forms in Metropolis?
Can I show a Form  which is in a package in a layout of Master form? 

With best regards
Tomislav

Comment: `Actually question is: how to set parent-child forms in Metropolis?` Please consider to change the title of your post.

Comment: @Tomislav did you try the package Form's [`Parent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.Parent) property yet?

Comment: Ok, Suggestion is "in place" so I change title...